# Select from mysql database where columns contains PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and some of the columns contain things like CA, GB etc, although some contain multiple country codes like

US+GB+CA+AU

I'm just wondering what kind of query I would do that would return that row when I'm searching for just CA or just GB, and no necessarily the whole package US+GB+CA+AU

Encase that's a little confusing, basically I just need to return that row based on a search for just CA or just GB etc.

Thanks

Comment: Why do some of your columns contain multiple data? I'd advise you to look at that and try and normalise it. It will cause you no end of problems...

Comment: it just the way the data was being stored in a csv before i imported it, i may very well just normalise it.

Comment: In that case I would normalise your schema now. It's easy enough to split the concatenated strings in the csv before you import the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`FIND_IN_SET()`,](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) but you'll first need to replace `+` with `,` since it expects a comma-separated string.  Even without the 
`REPLACE()`, this is will not make use of any index on the countrycodes column.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('AU', REPLACE(countrycodes, '+', ',')) > 0
```

The proper long term solution, however, is to change your database structure to normalize these country codes into a table that contains only two columns - a country code, and the id of the associated row from the table you're attempting to query now. You can then index the column appropriately to improve performance (possibly drastically improve it).

Comment: I believe according to [the MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), the correct syntax for `REPLACE` would be `REPLACE(countrycodes, '+', ',')`.

Comment: @Travesty3 Yes, you're correct thanks. I just did a string replacement in a different language with params in the other order...

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to normalise it like liquorvicar said.

but using **SELECT ... WHERE `countrycode` LIKE '%GB%'** would work.
http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good solution, but you can use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) for your query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` LIKE '%+CA+%' OR `field` LIKE 'CA+%' OR `field` LIKE '%+CA' OR `field` = 'CA'
```

Last two checks for firs and last values.

Comment: that's not necessary. % is a substitute for zero or more characters

Comment: @CarrieKendall but we have `LIKE '%+CA+%'` not `LIKE '%CA%'`. First value is not `+`

Comment: @CarrieKendall: I think the idea is to be extra safe in case you get a value like `CCA`, which you don't want to be returned.

Comment: but those ONLY return the records that have multiple country codes. Read OP's first sentence.

Comment: @CarrieKendall: A good point. You should add `OR field = 'CA'` to the `WHERE` clause. @MarcusAdams: Agreed, which is why I was referring to it as "extra safe" :-)